# How can I deploy pods in the same node in AWS EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to deploy pods in the same node in the EKS cluster.

for e.g if I deploy with the following command

`kubectl apply -f <deployment.yaml>`

is there a way to assign the deployments to a specific node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `nodeSelector` labels and pod `affinity`

NodeSelector example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    disktype: ssd
```

Pod affinity example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name
            operator: In
            values:
            - e2e-az1
            - e2e-az2
```

[Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)

Comment: thanks for reaching out. What if I am using a ```kind: deployment``` instead of ```kind: Pod```. Can I specify the nodeSelector in the ```template``` section of the file?

Comment: Yes, you can. Use the same syntax.
The `Deployment` is just a "hat" over the `Pod`